# can not find symbol class Builder

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Criei um projeto no Android Studio 1.0, Login Activity.

Fiz as seguintes mundanças:
No Build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 21        
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"  

dependencies {                                                      
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')               
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'               
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'           
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:6.5.+'       
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:6.5.+'   
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')                  
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')                    
}
```

Tenho uma classe chamado LoginActivity.java e outra PlusBaseActivity.java

O classe PlusBaseActivity.java, apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
can not find symbol class Builder
```

Parte do codigo que contém o erro:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initialize the PlusClient connection.
    // Scopes indicate the information about the user your application will be able to access.
    mPlusClient =
            new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).
                    setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/CheckInActivity")
                    .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN,
                    Scopes.PLUS_ME).build();
}
```

Já pesquisei pela internet e ainda não encontrei a solução, alguma dica como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Outra sugestão é usar as depêndencias do **Google Play Services** e o **Support Library** via Gradle, e não com o jar. Use `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'`, e no caso do **play-services** não está duplicando?

Answer (score 2):

Pesquisei sobre o assunto, encontrei que `PlusClient` não é mais aprovada (*deprecated*), se mesmo assim ainda quiser usá-la, utilize uma versão anterior da API, desse jeito:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
}
```

Recomendo que você procure mais informações sobre a [GoogleApiClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html), pois ela é uma API unificada que permite a integração com os serviços do Google Play.

**Referências**

[can not find symbol class Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27389192/can-not-find-symbol-class-builder)
[New Client API Model in Google Play Services](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2014/02/new-client-api-model-in-google-play.html)
[Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)
[Accessing Google APIs](http://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html)

Comment: Quem deu o downvote poderia se manifestar para que eu possa melhorar a resposta? E corrigir caso exista alguma falha nela!

Comment: Ainda vou testar as sugestões. Obrigado pelas dicas a todos